# how to install Adobe Acrobat Pro update as Windows administrator

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I've set the Adobe Acrobat Pro EXE to run as Administrator, but updates launched via the main executable apparently do not inherit admin rights (and fail with an error about unable to write to c:\config.msi folder).  The Adobe "update available" icon is in the system tray.  I don't see how to tell it to run as Administrator. Can it be done?

P.S. Right clicking on the icon in the Notification Area does not reveal a Run as Administrator option.

Comment: if you click on the "update available" icon in the system tray, if it needs admin rights to run, it should prompt for that

Comment: Can you right click on the acrobat icon and select run as admin? Then it would be under help or about (on mobile), check for updates.

Comment: No, right-clicking doesn't reveal a Run as Administrator option.

Comment: I'd like to know what it is about the question that got the downvote, so that I can improve it.